# naming style used by Javascript when creating properties whose value is an object

Tags: javascript, angular6

In my `Angular` code, I am creating an object as follows

```
{thumbnailContext: new ThumbnailContext(divId, 
        imgId,
        closeId,
        imageString,this.thumbnailContainerRef.length,null)}
```

if I want to access imgId, would I had to do `thumbnailContext.thumbnailContext.imgId`. Capital `T` i.e. `thumbnailContext.ThumbnailContext.imgId` doesn't work. Is it expected behavior??

`ThumbnailContext` class is

```
export class ThumbnailContext{
  constructor(public divId:string,
              public imgId: string,
              public closeId:string,
              public imgSrc:string,
              public index:number,
              public viewRefId:EmbeddedViewRef<ThumbnailContext>){} //TODOM - not sure if the types are correct
}
```

Comment: How do you get `thumbnailContext.thumbnailContext`? I only see it in your code once...

Comment: Depends on what the ThumbnailContext constructor actually returns.

Answer (score 0):

As you have an object called `thumbnailContext`, then you should access to properties of object like that `thumbnailContext.imgId`. Let me show an example:

```
fooMethod() {
    const thumbnailContext = new ThumbnailContext('divId', '1', '2', '3', 4, null);
    let imgId = thumbnailContext.imgId;
    console.log(`imgId: ${ imgId }`)
}
```